# Kotlin conversion in Java lost specialization of collections?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotation-processor, android-kripton

I'm working on an Annotation Processor based library for Android. I'm trying to improve library compatibility with Kotlin. I have the following situation:

```
@BindType(value = "rss")
class RssFeed(
        @BindSqlColumn(columnType = ColumnType.UNIQUE)
        val uid: String,

        @BindXml(xmlType = XmlType.ATTRIBUTE)
        val version: String,

        @Bind("channel")
        @BindSqlRelation(foreignKey = "rssFeedId")
        val channels: List<Channel>,

        val id: Long
)
```

As you can see this a simple data class in kotlin. My library will aspect that every collection is "specialized" (with generic). When I try to decompile this class in its equivalent in Java I obtain:

```
@BindType("rss")
@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 1, 10},
   bv = {1, 0, 2},
   k = 1,
   d1 = {"\u0000$\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u000e\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010 \n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\t\n\u0002\b\t\b\u0007\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B+\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u0003\u0012\f\u0010\u0005\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\u00070\u0006\u0012\u0006\u0010\b\u001a\u00020\t¢\u0006\u0002\u0010\nR\u001c\u0010\u0005\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\u00070\u00068\u0006X\u0087\u0004¢\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u000b\u0010\fR\u0011\u0010\b\u001a\u00020\t¢\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\r\u0010\u000eR\u0016\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u00038\u0006X\u0087\u0004¢\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u000f\u0010\u0010R\u0016\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u00038\u0006X\u0087\u0004¢\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u0011\u0010\u0010¨\u0006\u0012"},
   d2 = {"Lcom/abubusoft/rssreader/service/model/RssFeed;", "", "uid", "", "version", "channels", "", "Lcom/abubusoft/rssreader/service/model/Channel;", "id", "", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;J)V", "getChannels", "()Ljava/util/List;", "getId", "()J", "getUid", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "getVersion", "production sources for module app"}
)
public final class RssFeed {
   @BindSqlColumn(
      columnType = ColumnType.UNIQUE
   )
   @NotNull
   private final String uid;
   @BindXml(
      xmlType = XmlType.ATTRIBUTE
   )
   @NotNull
   private final String version;
   @Bind("channel")
   @BindSqlRelation(
      foreignKey = "rssFeedId"
   )
   @NotNull
   private final List channels;
   private final long id;

   @NotNull
   public final String getUid() {
      return this.uid;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String getVersion() {
      return this.version;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final List getChannels() {
      return this.channels;
   }

   public final long getId() {
      return this.id;
   }

   public RssFeed(@NotNull String uid, @NotNull String version, @NotNull List channels, long id) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(uid, "uid");
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(version, "version");
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(channels, "channels");
      super();
      this.uid = uid;
      this.version = version;
      this.channels = channels;
      this.id = id;
   }
}
```

As you can notice, the information about specialization of channel field is lost: it is signed as List.

It was expected that Java version of class mantains specialization of List.

It's something that I mistake, or simply Kotlin work in this way?

**UPDATE**

It's a very strange behaviour. Generic used on interface are recognized, the ones on the class no.

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
import com.abubusoft.kripton.android.annotation.BindDao
import com.abubusoft.kripton.android.annotation.BindSqlDynamicWhere
import com.abubusoft.kripton.android.annotation.BindSqlSelect
import com.abubusoft.kripton.android.annotation.BindSqlUpdate
import com.abubusoft.kripton.example.rssreader.service.model.Article

@BindDao(Article::class)
interface DaoArticle {

    @BindSqlUpdate(where = "id=:id")
    fun update(id: Long, read: Boolean)

    @BindSqlSelect
    fun selectByChannel(@BindSqlDynamicWhere where: String): LiveData<List<Article>>

    @BindSqlSelect(where = "id=:id")
    fun selectById(id: Long): List<Article>

    @BindSqlSelect(where = "id in (:ids)")
    fun selectByChannelUd(ids: List<Long>): List<Article>

    @BindSqlSelect(where = "guid=:guid")
    fun selectByGuid(guid: String): Article
}
```

Comment: More likely that your _decompiler_ loses the information, not that Kotlin loses it.

Comment: If I clearly understand, you miss generics after decompiling. This is the way how generics works. They are clearing after compilation. See "Type Erasure": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: Ok, it was clear for me. But the problem is. I work with a Java Annotation Processor on a Kotlin source (with kapt)..Does it works with Kotlin source code or with a Java source code (like the compiled one)?